# Have I calculated the probability of these z-scores correctly?

Tags: probability, statistics

For a normal distribution, use the given z-scores to find the requested probability:

Q1:
Find the probability greater than or equal to a z-score of 2

A1:
P(z>2) = 1 - p(z<2) = 1 - .9972 = .0228 or 2.28%

Q2:
Find the probability less than or equal a z-score of -2

A2:
p(p<-2) = .0228 or 2.28%

Q3:
Find the probability less than or equal to a z-score of 2

A3:
p(z<2) = .9972 or 97.72%

Q4:
Find the probability between z-scores of -1.50 and 2

A4:
p(-1.50 < z < 2) = .0668 + .9772 = 1.044 or 104.4%

I do not feel right about the last question especially since a probability shouldn't exceed 100%.

Please help
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You got the first three correct. I verified the calculations using R statistical software:

```
> 1-pnorm(2)
[1] 0.02275013
> pnorm(-2)
[1] 0.02275013
> pnorm(2)
[1] 0.9772499
> pnorm(2)-pnorm(-1.5)
[1] 0.9104427
```

You are correct that a probability should never exceed $1$. For problem $4$ you need to find the probability of being $between$ $-1.5$ and $2$. So you need to find the probability of being less than $2$ and subtract the probability of being less than $-1.5$. We have,

$$\begin{align*}
P(-1.5<Z<2)
&=P(Z<2)-P(Z<-1.5)\\\\
&\approx0.9772-0.0668\\\\
&\approx0.9104
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Looking to learn about your code for alignment. Changed to cap Z for RV.

Answer (score 1):

Next time, if it helps, try to visualize it!

[image]

We're talking about what the probability is that a random observation has a given z-score. $P(Z<2)$ corresponds to everything blue (including the green overlap). $P(Z<-1.5)$ corresponds to the green part. So $P(-1.5<Z<2)$ is the only blue part, which we can evidently see is $P(Z<2)-P(Z<-1.5)$

Comment: Nice graph (+1). Mind saying what software you used?

Comment: used Desmos @BruceET